# How do I correctly patch a module level property?

Tags: python, unit-testing, aws-lambda, mocking, monkeypatching

I have a Lambda function written in Python that looks like this:

```py
# lambda_function.py
from data_manager import DataManager

_data_manager = DataManager()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return _data_manager.do_something(event['value'])
```

The DataManager instance is stored in a module level property because it's a bit expensive to create. This way, it's only created on cold starts. It looks like this:

```py
# data_manager.py
from os import environ

class DataManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self._api_key = environ['ApiKey']

    def do_something(self, value: int):
        return value * 2
```

It's more complicated in reality but this illustrates the problem I'm running into, which is I can't figure out how to correctly patch the DataManager in a unit test. Here's the first thing I tried:

```py
# test_lambda_function.py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('lambda_function._data_manager', autospec=True)
def test_lambda_handler(mock_data_manager):
    print('test_lambda_handler called')
```

This test fails because `environ['ApiKey']` isn't set. My expectation was that the `DataManager.__init__` method wouldn't be called because `lambda_function._data_manager` is patched, but obviously that doesn't work. The `'test_lambda_handler called'` message is never even printed, I assume because the error occurs when the interpreter processes the `@patch` annotation. Next, I tried this:

```py
# test_lambda_function.py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('lambda_function.DataManager', autospec=True)
def test_lambda_handler(mock_data_manager):
    print('test_lambda_handler called')
```

This test fails for the same reason as the previous one. Next attempt:

```py
# test_lambda_function.py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('data_manager.DataManager', autospec=True)
def test_lambda_handler(mock_data_manager):
    print('test_lambda_handler called')
```

This test passes, but I run into more problems when it gets a little more complicated and I add another test using the same approach:

```py
# test_lambda_function.py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('data_manager.DataManager', autospec=True)
def test_lambda_handler(mock_data_manager):
    print('test_lambda_handler called')

    event = {'value': 1}
    expected = 2

    mock_data_manager.return_value.do_something.return_value = expected

    from lambda_function import lambda_handler
    actual = lambda_handler(event, {})

    assert expected == actual

@patch('data_manager.DataManager', autospec=True)
def test_lambda_handler_again(mock_data_manager):
    print('test_lambda_handler_again called')

    event = {'value': 2}
    expected = 4

    mock_data_manager.return_value.do_something.return_value = expected

    from lambda_function import lambda_handler
    actual = lambda_handler(event, {})

    assert expected == actual
```

In this case, the first test passes, but the second test fails because `lambda_function._data_manager` is still referencing the previous mock instance used in the first test. Apparently the property is only assigned when the `lambda_function` module is imported, and it's only imported once per test module, regardless of the fact that each test imports the `lambda_handler` function separately.

The only other idea I have is to not test the `lambda_function` module at all, but that's not really an option for various reasons.

Comment: If you want the lambda handler to be really re-imported, you have to remove it from the module cache first. e.g. something like `if 'lambda_handler' in sys.modules: del sys.modules['lambda_handler']`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I don't necessarily want that, it was just an attempt to make it go, but if that's the cleanest solution then I guess it's fine.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a clean solution, I just don't know a better one... This is always a problem with global variables set at load time, and in the long run I would rather refactor the code to avoid them.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen how would you refactor the code in a way that avoids reinitializing the DataManager between warm starts?

Comment: I would use lazy initialization, e.g. add a `data_manager()` function or method that creates the object on first access, which you can then patch. You can also move it into a singleton class.